# Is it possible to encode mastercard virtual debit cards to physical card?

Tags: encoding, emv, mastercard

My Bank provides me the hability to have virtual cards, for online shopping and more secure as I can disable them, limit the debit amount etc.

As you know the virtual cards only have the 3 informations : PAN, EXP date and CVV.

I have a virtual card for each online service I use so I know exactly how much I spend on each service : one for Netflix, one for spotify, one for github, one for 1and1...

But in real life it's kind limiting and I can't have more than one physical card from the bank. Ordering a new one disables the old one.

**Question** :
Is it possible to encode a blank new EMV chip card from my virtual cards and get it working?
Like cloning **my own card**, changing these values and reencoding a new one?

There are some printers and encoders like the EVOLIS Primacy which technical specs should do the job but I'm not sure it's as simple as just typing the PAN, EXP, CVV, card holder and voila!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you have the card number, expiry date and CVV2. But for a plastic card below are required

1. Track 2 data on magnetic stripe behind the card and inside chip. For this you need to have Card Verification Key for generating CVV(for mag) and iCVV(for chip) - which you don't have.
2. An EMV transaction is protected by a cryptogram which is unique for a transaction. For this you need Issuer Master Key for Application Cryptogram - which you don't have.
3. Chip contains ICC Private key for generating signed certificate as a part of Offline Data Authentication - which you don't have.

So the answer is you simply cannot.

Comment: I fully agree with Adarsh on this with a small remark regarding point 3 - Offline Data Authentication is not mandatory to issue a card. Some non-expiring online-only cards do not offer this function at all and it is compliant with scheme rules.

Comment: No, firstly a few tags can be changed post issuance and card number will not be in the list. Secondly the unique key for cryptogram placed on the card is based on the original card number. So you will never get the cryptogram right.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to clone Chip based EMV cards. Cloning was possible in early age mag stripe cards but it is not possible to read complete data from Smart card base EMV cards.
[enter link description here](https://www.cryptomathic.com/news-events/blog/reducing-payment-card-fraud-by-shifting-over-to-emv-chip-technology)